# Three lines are concurrent (or parallel) $\iff$ the determinant of its coordinates vanishes.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant, affine-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

I'm trying to prove the concurrency condition for three lines lying on a plane. This condition says that:

> Let 
>   \begin{cases} ax + by + cz=0 \\ a'x – b'y + c'z=0 \\ a''x + b''y + c''z=0 \end{cases}
>   be three lines (barycentric coordinates), with the cordinates of the lines not all equal. Prove that they are concurrent or parallel iff $$ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
> a & b & c \\
> a' & b' & c' \\
> a'' & b'' & c'' \end{array} \right| =0.
> $$

My try:

> $$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
> a & b & c \\
> a' & b' & c' \\
> a'' & b'' & c'' \end{array} \right| =0 \iff \exists P=(x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0),$$
>
> and we've found a common $P$ in those three lines, different of $(0,0,0)$ and with $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, because it would follow that $P=(0,0,0)$. So the lines are concurrent.

Is it correct? How I see that they're parallel?

Comment: If atleast two of the lines are parallel then that determinant will be zero because their coeffiecients will be proportional. If the determinant is zero, then we can say that the lines meet at infinity

Comment: @G-man Why if the determinant is $0$ we can say that the lines meet at infinity?

Comment: What if you find a solution (x,y,z) such that x+y+z=0?

Answer (score 1):

I have also tackled this problem recently. It looks very easy and a basic problem, and yet I haven't been able to convince myself of this proposition.

What I did:

If the determinant |A| is 0, then the rank of the coefficient matrix
is $\leq 2$.

Thus, the zero space of the given system of equations A x = 0 has dimension at least $\geq 1$.

So, any solution to the system looks like
\[
x'(t) = (tA, B, -1)^{transpose} \quad t \in \mathbb{R}
\]
for some fixed $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$,
if the dimension of the zero space is $1$.

Inserting x' into Ax = 0, we have 
\[
\begin{split}
taA + Bb - c & = 0, \\
ta'A + Bb' - c' & = 0, \\
ta''A + Bb'' - c'' & = 0 .
\end{split}
\]

Solving for B in each relation, we have
 \[
\begin{split}
B & = - taA/b + c/b, \\
B & = - ta'A/b' + c'/b', \\
B & = - ta''A/b'' + c''/b''
\end{split}
\]
for all real $t$, and this is possible if coefficients 
are equal to one another; that is, each relation is of the form
\[
y = a x + c_{i}, \quad i = 1, 2, 3.
\]

If solutions to Ax = 0 look like 
\[
x'(t) = (tA, tB, -1)^{transpose} \quad t \in \mathbb{R},
\]
we can still equate
\[
- taA/b + c/b = - ta'A/b' + c'/b'
\]
and use the same argument concerning coefficients of linear equations.

But I do not think this is correct. Just a suggestion so that anyone
else might correct me.